# POST PARAMETERS FAIL

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

I need to use **curl** to call some API  and this is my function:

```
$url = ........
$curl_data = array('name'=>$name);
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_data);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

This is the function that I call with the url in the curl call:

```
function getFunction() {
        $name = $this->input->post ( 'name' );
}
```

but when I print `"$name"`, **the value that I read is null**. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Try using `$_POST` instead of `$this->input->post`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set curl option to use POST method. CURLOPT_POST

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: If POSTFIELDS include POST!

Comment: The documentation does not suggest that just by using POSTFIELDS , it will use the the method 'POST' .. so I would be carefull and at least give it a try by setting the CURLOPT_POST .